# Form validation return issues

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Im trying to learn form validation and I cannot figure out what is going on here. I am following a W3Schools tutorial and **the validate form function is giving an error** but it is not doing that on their example.

I tried copy and pasting the example into my project and just changing the property name and it still gives an error.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["contact"]["yourName"].value;

    if (x == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Your Name");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="contact" onsubmit="validateForm()">

    <label for="cakeName">Cake name:</label>
    <select required name="cakes" id="cakes">
        <option value="placeholder">--- Select cake ---</option>
        <option value="cakeOne">Coconut Bundt Cake</option>
        <option value="cakeTwo">Cream Cheese Pound Cake</option>
        <option value="cakeThree">German Chocolate Cake</option>
        <option value="cakeFour">Classic Yellow Cake</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <label for="yourName">Your name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <br>

    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <input name="message" type="text" placeholder="type your text you want written on the cake">
    <br>

    <label for="includes">Includes:</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="candle" name="candle" value="Candle">
    <label for="candle">Candle</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="candle" name="candle" value="Candle">
    <label for="candle">Firework</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="candle" name="candle" value="Candle">
    <label for="candle">Toys</label>
    <br>

    <label for="deliveryDate">Deliver Date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
    <br>

    <label for='deliverTo'>Deliver to:</label>
    <textarea name='deliverTo' id="deliverTo" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>

    <label for="callBefore">Call before deliver?</label>

    <input type='radio' id="yes" name="callBefore" value="Yes">
    <label for="yes">Yes</label>

    <input type='radio' id="no" name="callBefore" value="No">
    <label for="no">No</label>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="bar">Order Now</button>

</form>
```

Comment: change **name="yourName"** at **<input name="name" type="text">** as the dom is trying to accept value of yourName and you have not user yourName at any input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with your code:

1. The field `name` was wrong.
2. You need to prevent your from default behavior which is reload or redirect to process it's data before submiting.

```js
function validateForm(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); // You didn't stop the subminssion default behavior
    
    let x = document.forms["contact"]["yourName"].value;

    if (x == "") {
        alert("Please Enter Your Name");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="contact" onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
    <label for="yourName">Your name:</label>
    <!-- You used a wrong name -->
    <input name="yourName" type="text">

    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="bar">Order Now</button>
</form>
```

---

## How we handle forms these days

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#contact-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (ev)=>{
  // Stop the form submission from reloading or redirecting
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  let yourName = document.querySelector('#your-name').value;
  
  if(yourName === ""){
    alert("Please Enter Your Name");
    return;
  }
  
  // Post the form with Fetch API or Axios ...
});
```

```html
<form id="contact-form">
    <label for="yourName">Your name:</label>
    <input name="yourName" id="your-name" type="text">

    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="bar">Order Now</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem (what was the error?) but the following line:

```
<input name="name" type="text">
```

Should be:

```
<input name="yourName" type="text">
```